# Getting current class name including parent class name?

Tags: c#, .net

If I have a class B and C which inherits from A, is there something simpler than using StackFrame's GetFileName() (then parse out the ClassName.cs string)?

If I use this.GetType().Name, it won't return "A" when the code is executing in the parent class.

**Sample Code**

```
namespace StackOverflow.Demos
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B myClass = new C();
            string containingClassName = myClass.GetContainingClassName();
            Console.WriteLine(containingClassName); //should output StackOverflow.Demos.B
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class A { public A() { } }
    public class B : A { public B() { } }
    public class C : B { public C() { } }

}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand your question without at least a small example. Could you please show a small code snippet that does something close to what you're trying to achieve, and tell us how the output differs from what you want?

Comment: Sorry.. if "this" is of type B, while it's running in parent A's constructor, I'd like to get the classname "A". Most of the Q&A code  I've seen wants it to return "B"... but I want it to return "A".

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect what you were after (see first answer).  There's probably a better way than this; having a play now - but this works for the time being.

Comment: ps. thinking about it there may not be a better way than using overloading - as any method to get the container type would need to be implemented on the object class; so would always return object (i.e. imagine writing an extension method to provide this functionality for an instance of any class and you'll see the problem).  Also generally in the code you'd know what the parent class was, as it's declared there - and if you've passed the object to a different parent/container the previous context (i.e. what the parent was when the variable was declared) would have been lost).

Answer (score 9):

```
var yourType = GetType();
var baseType = yourType.BaseType;
```

or alternatively:

```
var currentTypeName = new StackFrame(1, false).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks... but the alternative code you posted still returns "B" when the thread is running in parent A's constructor.

Comment: @user1279437 When creating a `new C()`, when running the "chained" instance constructors of the base classes, the `this` reference is still considered to be a `C`. Similarly when running methods inherited from base classes. If you want a "constant" type, say e.g. `typeof(A)` instead of saying `GetType()` inside some instance constructor or instance method inside class `A`.

Answer (score 1):

I use `myObject.GetType().FullName` which returns the fully qualified name of the class. For your scenario, you could use `myObject.GetType().BaseType.FullName`

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 :: Getting the "container" class:**

```
/**CODE**/

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B c = new C();
        Test(c);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void Test(A a) { Console.WriteLine(typeof(A).ToString()); }
    public static void Test(B b) { Console.WriteLine(typeof(B).ToString()); }
    public static void Test(C c) { Console.WriteLine(typeof(C).ToString()); }

/**OUTPUT**/

    StackOverflow.Demos.B
```

**Option 2 :: Getting the "container" class:**

```
/**CODE**/

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B myClass = new C();
            Console.WriteLine(myClass.GetContainerType()); //should output StackOverflow.Demos.B
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public interface IGetContainerType
    {
        Type GetContainerType();
    }

    public class A: IGetContainerType 
    { 
        public A() { }
        public Type GetContainerType()
        {
            return typeof(A);
        }
    }
    public class B : A
    {
        public B() { }
        public new Type GetContainerType()
        {
            return typeof(B);
        }
    }
    public class C : B
    {
        public C() { }
        public new Type GetContainerType()
        {
            return typeof(C);
        }
    }

/**OUTPUT**/

    StackOverflow.Demos.B
```

**Answer to similar but different question; Getting the instance class / full hierarchy:**

```
/**CODE**/

    class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            C c = new C();
            Type myType = c.GetType();
            while(myType != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myType);
                myType = myType.BaseType;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


/**OUTPUT**/

    StackOverflow.Demos.C
    StackOverflow.Demos.B
    StackOverflow.Demos.A
    System.Object
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `GetType()`, or equivalently `this.GetType()`, you get the actual type of the class. For example

```
class A
{
  public void Test()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(GetType().Name);
  }
}

class B : A
{
}
```

and later:

```
var myB = new B();
myB.Test();   // writes B to the console
```

I guess that's what [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) is all about.

If you want always `A`, no polymorphism, simply say:

```
class A
{
  public void Test()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(A).Name);
  }
}

class B : A
{
}
```